# Why does mypy complain that inclusion checks in optional lists aren't always booleans?

Tags: python, mypy, typing

I have the following piece of code (expanded out for a clearer explanation) that I expected to always have boolean variable types. However, mypy indicates that the second and third types are not always `bool` but instead a union of `list`, `None`, and `bool`.

```py
a: list[str] | None = None
b: list[str] | None = None

def f(test: str) -> bool:
    flag: bool = not a and not b
    flag2: bool = a and test in a
    flag3: bool = b and test not in b
    return flag or flag2 or flag3
```

If I change the second line to `a is not None` (along with the third), the indicated typing becomes correct. Shouldn't the types resolve to boolean since the expressions are always conditionals? Why is the `is not None` necessary?

Here is the playground link showing the error: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&flags=verbose&gist=14167cfb7554c2c94c3bd65d2710d017

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`and`** in Python is not a Boolean operation, though it can be (and often is) used as one. `a and b` will return the `a` if it is falsy, or `b` otherwise. To see why this definition can function as a Boolean operation:

```py
False and False == False  # (a is falsy, result is a)
False and True  == False  # (a is falsy, result is a)
True and False  == False  # (a is not falsy, result is b)
True and True   == True   # (a is not falsy, result is b)
```

However, with non-Boolean operands:

```py
"" and 0        == ""  # (a is falsy, result is a)
"" and 42       == ""  # (a is falsy, result is a)
"answer" and 0  == 0   # (a is not falsy, result is b)
"answer" and 42 == 42  # (a is not falsy, result is b)
```

When coerced to a Boolean, e.g. by a conditional, it still functions as if the result was Boolean, but it is not. Thus, the type of the result of an `and` operation is a union of the types of its arguments. Since `a` is `list[str] | None` and `test in a` is a `bool`, `a and test in a` is `list[str] | None | bool`. Specifically, if `a` is `[]`, which still falls under `list[str]`, then `flag2` would end up as a non-Boolean `[]`.

Comment: Ahh I see - coercion just for the evaluation but not the return. That makes sense. So the `is not` is an explicit conditional on the left side, thus making it `bool | bool -> bool`, fixing the problem.

Comment: There are no conditionals in your code. A "conditional" is a syntactic form in a language that takes a condition, like `if` or `while`; it is a part of Python's semantics that a conditional will coerce its condition into a Boolean in order to decide its course of action. If you intended to say that `is not` operator produces a Boolean value, you are correct.

Comment: Oh, also, for completeness sake: yes, `return` does not coerce, it just returns whatever it is given. With that in mind, you could also have fixed the problem by explicit coercion: `return bool(flag or flag2 or flag3)`, without changing anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike some other languages, in Python an `and` expression does not necessarily return a bool value.

Instead, it returns the first value if it is falsey, otherwise it returns the second value.

```
a and test in a
```

if `a` is falsey (in this case perhaps it is an empty list) the `and` will return that value.